# How does Tkinter text widget handle hex 00-1F

Tags: python, tkinter, text, widget

Please consider the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
ts = '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\x0b\x0c\x0d\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13' \
     '\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1fabcdefghihk\nlmnopqrstuvwxyz'
root = Tk()
tb = Text(root, width = 50, height = 10)
tb.pack()
tb.insert("1.0", ts)
root.mainloop()
```

Are there special considerations in Tkinter for handling hex characters 00 through 1F (obviously excluding hex 09 and hex 0A? This short video shows the behavior of the code. As you can see, clicking and selecting the line produces different results.

[Tkinter Textbox with Hex 00-1F characters](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VUll2UArrwiu0stWw-uzOkl0VZwpRIUe)

Is there a way to translate these characters to display their ascii equivalent such as NUL, SOH, STX, 
etc.? Or is this just the standard behavior for Tkinter? Or is this something that would be better handled through some sort of encoding/decoding before inserting into the Text widget?

Thanks

Comment: Those aren't "ASCII equivalents" of the characters; they're short-hand names for the characters. This isn't the standard behaviour "for Tkinter"; it's the standard behaviour of *the font you are displaying the text in*.

Comment: You can simply go through all characters in the text and translate to whatever you want if the character is not printable before inserting to text widget.

Comment: If you are not satisfied with that font, find/create an OK one.